# How to run a Php web file in kali linux

Tags: php, xampp

I am trying to open up my php web files for my project in kali (o.s). I was previously using Xampp in Windows which run well however when i try to install Xampp in kali it gives me a warning not a secure program. Is there any other method or is it possible to use the  apache2 service.Any advice on how to solve this problem will be much appreciated.

Installing Xampp became an issue and i could not run my php web files.I have tried using the apache2 service however with no luck

Comment: XAMPP is fine. The warning you've seen might be just because it isn't downloaded from the operating system's registered package sources.

Comment: Alternately you can install your own Apache/MySQL/PHP components from the package manager I would expect. Did you research it at all? It uses Debian packages as far as I know, so you should be able to install the components pretty easily using apt. P.S. `I have tried using the apache2 service however with no luck` is a meaningless, information-free description that we can't fix. You'd have to give us a proper problem description to get any help with that.

Comment: P.S. Kali is designed specifically for pen-testers etc. Using it as a dev environment for running PHP apps etc isn't an obvious choice. Why not just use Ubuntu or Debian, or similar?

Comment: @ADyson  thanks for the info & helping me remember the  main purpose of kali linux. I just got used to it and attached while using it for the past 7 months for my cybersec goal an. I do have Ubuntu will be switching to it. Thanks for the reminder.